# Is my sample homogeneous?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

I have a sample of 110 values between 0 and 180. These represent total degrees in an arc, and I want to be able to figure out whether or not I have a widely variable sample of arc sizes or if I have a more homogeneous sample. I have a mean of 93.65 degrees and a standard deviation of 22.8 degrees. Can I tell this from the standard deviation? It seems homogeneous to me, but I don't know how to justify or negate this.

Comment: (1) What do these values represent? Of particular importance is whether values of $x$ and $x+180$ would be considered the same for any $x$. (2) Exactly what do you mean by "homogeneous"?

Comment: 1) These values are areas described in terms of "total degrees", but they are limited. There can be no value lower than 0 and no value higher than 180, as the items being measured are arcs located in semi-circles.
2) By homogenous, I mean, does the standard deviation shed any light on how alike, or unalike, the values are?

Comment: The SD tells you something about how *spread* out the values are. Whether that contains any information about how "alike" they are depends on what you mean by "alike"! What do you mean?

Comment: Do you maybe want to test for uniformity? There are many tests for circular uniformity, which test whether or not it is reasonable to assume that the data is uniform across all angles. However, this requires, as @whuber suggests, that 179 degrees is very close to 1 degrees. However, you seem to suggest that the range is bounded, which would suggest that a linear test for uniformity in the range 0-180 would be appropriate, if this is what you mean by homogeneity.

Answer (score 4):

Putting aside any potentially important issues relating to the suitability of means and standard deviations when your data are angles for a moment, let's address the more general issue -- standard deviation really isn't a measure of homogeneity.

It's quite possible to have two variables, one which might be regarded as homogeneous-but-somewhat-noisy and a second which clearly isn't homogeneous ... yet the second may well have a smaller standard deviation than the first.

In the diagram below, the data from which the green density was computed has a (slightly) smaller standard deviation than the more homogeneous-looking one marked in black.

[image]

Unless you can give a precise definition of what you mean by homogeneous, from which a suitable measure of homogeneity might be devised (and perhaps even then), the degree to which your data are "homogeneous" might be better assessed by a display, such as a kernel density estimate (or perhaps by a histogram with a moderately large number of bins).